# springboot logging.path VS executable jar LOG_FOLDER

Tags: spring-boot, logging

After setting logging.path in the application.yml, the logfile is written in logging.path.

But when we take the application to production. we build an executable jar, like app.jar, and we write a config file in the same folder like app.conf. In app.conf there is an option "LOG_FOLDER"

The reference book says:
"logFolder-The default value for LOG_FOLDER. Only valid for an init.d service."

So, I am so confused, which one determines where the logfile should be written?

Comment: I made a test. when both options are set, There will be two log files. The content of them is same. The log file under LOG_FOLDER will not be divided when it's size is larger than 10m.